# Postgres update a table (only) if it exists

Tags: postgresql

I have a Server and several Client Applications. The Server has to be started before a client can be started. The clients then create tables in the database if they don't exists.

When the Server is started (some tables do not exist) and the following query gives me an `exception`:

```
UPDATE recipes SET lock = null 
WHERE lock IS NOT NULL;
```

**`Relation >>recipes<< does not exists`**

I want to avoid this `exception` by checking if this table exists or not.

```
UPDATE recipes SET lock = null
WHERE lock IS NOT NULL AND
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   information_schema.tables 
   WHERE  table_schema = 'public'
   AND    table_name = 'recipes'
   );
```

But this `query` does not work. Can you tell me where my mistake is?

Comment: `WHERE lock IS NOT NULL AND WHERE EXISTS (`  should be `WHERE lock IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS ( ...` . But even like that, it cannot work. You can use  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-do.html for your case. `do $$ begin if..else.. end if; end$$`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need a pl/pgsql block to do the `IF`:

```
DO $$                  
    BEGIN 
        IF EXISTS
            ( SELECT 1
              FROM   information_schema.tables 
              WHERE  table_schema = 'public'
              AND    table_name = 'recipes'
            )
        THEN
            UPDATE recipes 
            SET lock = NULL
            WHERE lock IS NOT NULL ;
        END IF ;
    END
   $$ ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recipes (... )
```

And continue with update ...

see 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766046/postgresql-create-table-if-not-exists

Answer (score 0):

I tend to prefer:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
  UPDATE recipes SET lock = null 
  WHERE lock IS NOT NULL;
EXCEPTION WHEN UNDEFINED_TABLE THEN
  -- do nothing
END$$;
```